# Timber + ACF - How to get get_row_index() working?

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber, acfpro

**Problem:** I would need to get the current layout index from flexible content field. ACF already have built-in functionality for this - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row_index/

**Timber template:**

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    {% for flex_content in post.meta('flex_components') %}
        {{ get_row_index() }} <!-- I'm stuck here -->
        {% include [flex_content.acf_fc_layout|sanitize ~ '.twig'] ignore missing %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

**My current solution:** Is using a simple counter, but I would like to learn how to get this working with get_row_index() function (if is possible).

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}

    {% set my_counter = 1 %}
    {% for flex_content in post.meta('flex_components') %}
        {% include [flex_content.acf_fc_layout|sanitize ~ '.twig'] ignore missing %}
        {% set my_counter = my_counter + 1 %}
    {% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: @DarkBee No, that probably wouldn’t work, because that function relies on a context that is not set when using Timber.

Comment: @Gchtr I see, then just using the built-in `loop.index` is indeed a better solution then creating your own counter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can’t use `get_row_index()` when using Timber, because that function relies on a global variable set by ACF when using `have_rows()`, which we don’t have in Timber. This works similar to the WordPress Loop, which Timber tries to get rid of.

In Twig, you can always use the
[loop variable](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable) inside a `for` loop. This variable provides you with the counter you need.

```
{% extends "base.twig" %}

{% block content %}
    {{ dump(loop.index) }}

    {% for flex_content in post.meta('flex_components') %}
        {% include [flex_content.acf_fc_layout|sanitize ~ '.twig'] ignore missing %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Worth to mention that `loop.index` is 1 indexed

Comment: @DarkBee Yes, it’s good you mention that. I chose `loop.index` because [get_row_index()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_row_index/#notes) is 1 indexed, too.

Comment: Didn't know about the loop variable. Great, thanks!